# How to disable automatic indent?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, parskip

I know there are some similar questions here, but I haven't found the perfect answer for my problem.

I don't like that TeX indents he first line of each paragraph and I'm too lazy to write `\noindent` to the beginning of the paragraphs, so I use this: `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}` (I also tried the parskip package)

The only problem is that when I try to indent a line inside a paragraph with `\indent`, nothing happens. I also tried unbreakable spaces (`~~~~~~~`) but they didn't work.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: It would help the people who are trying to answer questions if you also provide a MWE showing the problem.

Comment: have you tried `\hspace*{length}`? note the `*` for it work at the beginning of a line.

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand why you want to suppress the indent, while using it sometimes. Either always use it or never; the former alternative is better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Before setting `\parindent` to zero, we can store its value in another length variable and redefine the `\indent` command to use this other length variable instead of `\parindent` (which has been set to zero).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newlength\tindent
\setlength{\tindent}{\parindent}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace*{\tindent}}

\begin{document}

This is some text that will not be indented.

\indent This is some text that will be indented.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 43):

For even lazier people. `;)`

You can use the [`parskip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package, just add `\usepackage{parskip}` to your preamble. From the documentation:

> Package to be used with any document class at any size. It produces
>   the following Paragraph Layout:
>   Zero Parindent and non-zero Parskip. The stretchable
>   glue in `\parskip` helps LATEX in ﬁnding the best place for
>   page breaks.

Comment: works like a charm !!

Comment: +1 since it has the advantage of putting extra space after paragraphs