# Unwanted right indent in document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

Super noob here, so please forgive any blunders! :)

My problem is that in my document (example below), the paragraph starting from the second dingbat is getting indented automatically. I don't want this; I want all the left edges aligned perfectly. How can this be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont} %For the very nice dingbats

\begin{document}

\section*{Elementary Algebra}

\ding{234} One amusing way to look at \textbf{irrational numbers} is to say that they don't behave rationally. The point is, given their non-terminating, non-repeating decimals, there's no `sane' way to work with them!

\ding{234} Here are some elementary but easily forgotten (and highly useful) algebraic identities:

\begin{itemize}

    \item $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your message be entitled "Unwanted `left`indent…?

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage{parskip}` does what you want?

Comment: Related/duplicate(s): [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42/5764); [How to disable automatic indent?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59245/5764)

Comment: I think the right here is to think about what that is first and how do you really want it to behave. May be it's just two items (then the answer @Bernard provided is right) or may be you just want `\paragraph{\ding{234}}` in those two (and many more) cases. If none of them fits you, it's possible that you are really looking to the `\usepackage{parskip}`, as they already said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either add `\noindent` before each \ding{234} (except the first: that would be useless), or set `\parindent=0pt` in your preamble – but you then should fix `\parskip` to a non zero value (say `\smallskipamount` for instance) so as to differentiate paragraphs.

You also could consider these paragraphs as items in a (1st level) itemize environment, load the  `enumitem`package and write:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{pifont} %For the very nice dingbats

    \begin{document}

    \section*{Elementary Algebra}
    \begin{itemize}[label = \ding{234},wide, labelindent = 0pt]

    \item One amusing way to look at \textbf{irrational numbers} is to say that they don't behave rationally. The point is, given their non-terminating, non-repeating decimals, there's no `sane' way to work with them!

    \item Here are some elementary but easily forgotten (and highly useful) algebraic identities:

    \begin{itemize}[label = \textbullet, align = left,  labelindent = 1.5em, labelsep* = 0.5em,labelwidth = 1em,  leftmargin =! ,topsep = 0pt]
        \item $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ 
        \item $a^3  +  b^3 = (a + b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$
    \end{itemize}

    \end{itemize}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible that he is looking more for a `\paragraph{\ding{234}}`. By the way what is that math doing inside an itemize (the extra cool thing is the en-dash before the math itself)? May be `\[ … \]` is what he is looking for.

Comment: @Manuel: Well, maybe but she/he'll should say so in such a case. As for the endash that looks like a minus sign, I hadn't noticed. I suppose it' used by default for second-level items. I changed it to a bullet, and slightly modified the vertical spacing.

Comment: One more: a `minipage` (by default `\parindent=0pt`)

Comment: @Fran: It's a solution, but there's a problem with page breaks.

Comment: @Bernard Very nice! And makes it look very neat! :-)